# Are there any sahabas of Muhammad (pbuh) who married trinity-believing christians?

Tags: nikah, christianity, sahaba, ahlul-kitab

I know that there are some sahabas of Muhammad pbuh who married christians. But what kind of christians were they? Did they believe in the trinity? Or were they non-trinitarian christians? Did they take Isa pbuh as a god?

Please provide evidences.

Comment: There are a few tausend sahaba known by name (based on their narration of hadith), much less of that about whom we have some more information in a couple of biographies (also primarily based on historical records and hadith narration). If by coincidence some of them did so we have only these two sources but without as much details as you seem to require!

Comment: But I want to know if Islam allows Muslims to marry christians who believe in trinity. There are some verses in the quran which say that believing in trinity makes you a mushrik. Doesn't that mean that once a christian starts believing in trinity, she is no longer an ahl-al-kitaab? That would make her ineligible for marriage.

Comment: If the qur'an still calls her ahl-al-kitab she has the status of ahl-al-kitab http://legacy.quran.com/98 as http://legacy.quran.com/5/5 is among the last revelations!